# IIS URL Rewrite with condition

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have a requirement to redirect an incoming request to IIS with the following

- Incoming: https://myurl.com/sites/testSite/library/XXXX.pdf
- Outgoing: https://myNewUrl.com/redirect/xxx.pdf
- Condition: Incoming request must contain sites/testSite/library

Answer (score 0):

You could try below rule to implement your requirement:

```
<rule name="rule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="test1.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/sites/testSite/library/(.*)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://test2.com/redirect/{C:1}" />
                </rule>
```